# Can’t set watermark in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, watermark

Magento 2.3.0 has bug - can’t upload watermark pictures in admin panel. 
I do next:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
```

**On approx lines 21, 81 and 140 each line, change fileUploader to imageUploader.**

`vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

**On approx line 16 change fileUploader to imageUploader.**

Now I can upload watermark, but pictures of product with watermark I see in small pictures only! There are no watermarks in Base, Thumbnail and Swatch pictures of poduct. 
How to fix this bug and set watermark to all product pictures?